# Destructuring assignment with rename and typing information

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

How do I destructure a variable into a new name while keeping typing information?

```
renderItem({item:'apple'})

// jsx:
function renderItem({item: region}) {
    // region == 'apple'
    return <div>{region}</div>;
}
```

The above will destructure an object with item and assign it to `region`.

How do I express typing information for this function signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Information about the typing of the feature is available in the TypeScript 2.1 documentation:

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html
>
> Object rests are the dual of object spreads, in that they can extract any extra properties that don’t get picked up when destructuring an element:

When the Rest portion of the feature is used, it enhances object destructuring by enabling us to collect the rest of the properties into a new object comprised of them.

We can write the type annotation as we would for any other value. This is prefered as it can stop your function signatures getting verbose For example

```
interface IRenderItem {
  item: String
}

function renderItem({ item: region }: IRenderItem): void {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the more detailed explanation!

Answer (score 10):

Type the incoming item like so:

```
function renderItem({item: region}:{item:string}){}
```

Comment: FYI, I couldn't find this info anywhere on SO, so after I figured it out I posted it here for others to find who run into the same problem.